# Adding two DC Power

Tags: dc

[image]If I add two different DC voltage(from different source) in same line i.e 1# 100V 1A and 2# 50V 5A. So can I get output as 150V 5A when I connect both in series ?

If there is any other alternative so that I will get maximum Power without any shot circuit. As both the sources are different.

Comment: The output power is higher than the input power !
100V x 1A = 100W, 50V x 5A = 250W
Total input: 100W + 250W = 350W, 
output: 150V x 6A = 750W
So what is the maximum current you can get at the output assuming 100% efficiency and 150V output voltage ?

Comment: Assuming you placed them in series (say they were completely isolated floating ground supplies), then at the output you would get 150V at 1A max. Why? Because the 100V supply can only source 1A and as the current is the same at all points in a series circuit, the current through source 2 and the load must also be limited to 1A.

Comment: If you put a 10A fuse in series with a 1A fuse, what current will the rating be?

Comment: @Jodes You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: @Andyaka fuses -> 1000A if at least one is not a HRC unit.

Answer (score 2):

The following assumes conversions at 100% efficiency.
This is not possible in practice but the results can be but adjusted later to allow for real world efficiencies.

---

Power out MUST be no more than Power in.
Power out <= Power In
Power = Volts x Amps.
(Vin1 x Iin1 + Vin2 x Iin2 >= Vout x Iout

100V x 1A  = 100W
50V x 5A = 250 W
Total power in = 100 + 250 = 350W

However it is achieved, output must have
Power out = Vout x Iout  <= 350
eg 350V x 1A   or
35V x 10A  or
175V x 2A

---

**Converting the voltage from one supply:**

If you do not care what voltage Vout is you could convert one voltage to be the same as the other.

Two sources at the same voltage can be added in parallel **with proper design of the circuitry involved.**

So eg
100V x 1A -> 50V x 2A
50V x (5A input + 2A converted ) = 50V at 7A

or
50V x 5A -> 100V at 2.5A
100 V x (1A input + 2.5A convereted) = 100V at 3.5A

Power = 100 x 3.5 = 350 Watt

**Converting both supplies:**

With two co=nverters you caan do eg

100 @ 1A -> 250 V @ 0.4A
 50 @ 5A -> 250 V @ 1A
250V x (0.4 A + 1A ) = 250 V at 1.4A 
Power = 250 x 1.4 = 350 Watt.

---

**In series:**

You COULD also place one converted source in series with the other if they had the same current output and were isolated from each other.

100V x 1A -> 20V x 5A

In Series 20V x 5A (converted) + 50V x 5A = 70V x 5A
Power = 70V x 5A = 350W